# Is grep documentation about ignoring case wrong, since it doesn't ignore case in filenames?

Tags: grep, documentation

The [man page for `grep`](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/grep/grep.1.en.html) reads

> **`-i`**, **`--ignore-case`**
>
>     Ignore case distinctions in both the
>     *PATTERN*
>     and the input files. 
>       (
>     **`-i`**
>     is specified by POSIX.)

However, if I change case on a filename, it won't work.

```
$ touch WHATEVER
$ grep -i pattern whatever
grep: whatever: No such file or directory
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92610/discussion-on-question-by-grep-is-grep-documentation-wrong).

Comment: That switch is talking about the _content_ of the file, not its _name_.  The accepted answer does not at all address the problem shown here.

Comment: @MontyHarder The accepted answer implicitly confirms that the wording is confusing and supports that this is a non-issue in the new version.

Comment: @grep The problem you present is the non-existence of `whatever`, which the accepted answer does not in any way address. I am not aware of any version of grep that will look in `WHATEVER` when you ask it to look in `whatever`, under any circumstances. The accepted answer addresses `grep -i PATTERN whatever`, which is **not** `grep -i pattern WHATEVER`. Case-sensitivity of filenames is a *nix thing, not a `grep` thing.

Comment: I would never have considered the -i parameter to apply to the filename, based on reading either man page line.

Comment: @MontyHarder No, the problem I present is that of an alleged inconsistency between the man page and the displayed behavior. I could have very well asked the same question without the example, and then you wouldn't be able to claim what you're claiming.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That confusing snippet was changed in newer versions of GNU grep to:

> `-i`, `-ignore-case`
>   Ignore case distinctions, so that characters that differ only in case match each other.

See this commit: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/commit/?id=e1ca01be48cb64e5eaa6b5b29910e7eea1719f91

```
 .BR \-i ", " \-\^\-ignore\-case
-Ignore case distinctions in both the
-.I PATTERN
-and the input files.
+Ignore case distinctions, so that characters that differ only in case
+match each other.
```

---

As to where the old formulation may originate, some programs like `less(1)` have a (mis)feature[1] where using an uppercase letter in a pattern will turn off case insensitivity for a particular search (override the `-i` flag). The author of that doc snippet probably assumed that many people expected that behavior, and instead of some direct caveat, preferred that non-committal sentence. FWIW, such a feature was never a part of `ed(1)`, `grep(1)`, `vi(1)`, `perl(1)` etc. or of the `regex(3)` or `pcre(3)` APIs.

[1] that seems to have its origins in `emacs`, where it's the default; there you can turn it off by setting the (customizable) `search-upper-case` variable to `nil`.

Comment: Do you mind opening that link in private mode finding that part of the doc? I just went through all ten occurrences of "ignore" and couldn't find that bit.

Comment: sorry for the mixup

Comment: I find the `less` behaviour very useful. I would never use uppercase characters in my search query if I intended the search to be case sensitive. It's a sensible default IMO

Comment: Another possible origin is that case conversion is not necessarily symmetrical. For instance, both `fi` and `ﬁ` (U+FB01) translate to `FI` in uppercase (not on GNU systems it seems though), should `grep -i ﬁ` match on `ﬁ`, `ﬁ` and `FI`. What about `grep -i FI`?

Comment: Actually, it looks as if GNU `grep` does case insensitive matching by translating subject and regexp to uppercase. For instance, in an English locale `echo İ | grep -i i` doesn't match. The lowercase `İ` is `i`, but the uppercase `i` is `I` instead of `İ` (that's different in Turkish locales though).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Having to edit a mixed-case word that was copy-pasted is not *nice*, and that feature is non-symmetric -- what is the syntax to search in `less -i` for "hello" but not "Hello"? As to the interaction between case insensitive search, compatibility chars like `ﬁ` and locales, there are many nasty problems (while there, don't forget the titlecasing (eg ǈ, ǉ , Ǉ = U+01C7-U+01C9), another horrible contraption for a non-existing problem).

Comment: You can get all those behaviours in `less` by entering `-i` and `-I` within `less`. The default is case-sensitive, `-i` is the default chosen by mandb, git, and IMO is useful. For a complete case insensitive (like for your copy-paste case), there's `-I`. `vim` has the `smartcase` option as an equivalent of `less -i` behaviour. GNU `info` and GNU `emacs` behave like `less -i` in this instance.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas You're right. that's apparently coming from emacs. In emacs you can even (kind of) fix the copy-paste issue by settting the `search-upper-case` variable to `'not-yanks` (that only works with Ctrl-Y, not with middle-click, though).

Comment: What does any of this have to do with mis-cased filenames?

Comment: @MontyHarder Nothing. It only has to do with the meaning and origin of some confusing doc snippet, which is the subject of this Q&A, and which was fortunately fixed in recent versions of GNU grep.

Comment: @mosvy But the question does not in any way hinge on the "fix".  The documentation never suggested that filename case would be ignored; the "fix" still says "files" (not filenames) just like it did before.

Comment: @MontyHarder No, the newer version doesn't say anything at all about files. The old version was confusing and suggested a lot of things that were not true -- as I already told you, GNU grep has options like `--include` to filter the file*names*; they may just as well have casing capabilities, like the `-iname` from GNU find. That unfortunate description of `-i` may be reasonably interpreted in this context.

Comment: @MontyHarder I asked the question because I think the documentation suggests just that. Even if I'm gravely incorrect, that is what the question is about, that's the whole point.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently I have a different manpage.

```
   -i, --ignore-case
          Ignore case distinctions, so that characters that differ only in
          case match each other.
```

In any case, it's not about the filenames.

It ignores case in the file (contents) but also in the pattern.

Test file:

```
___________
Hello World
^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Grep results (ignore case of file contents):

```
$ grep hello test.txt 

$ grep Hello test.txt 
Hello World
$ grep -i HELLO test.txt 
Hello World
$ grep -i hello test.txt 
Hello World
```

Grep results (ignore case of pattern):

```
$ grep [a-Z] test.txt 
grep: Invalid range end
$ grep -i [a-Z] test.txt
Hello World
$ grep -i [A-z] test.txt
Hello World
$ grep [A-z] test.txt
___________
Hello World
^^^^^^^^^^^
```

As you can see the results can sometimes be a little unexpected.

Not sure if there is an example where this actually matters more.

Comment: "It ignores case in the file (contents) but also in the pattern", this suggests (although it doesn't necessarily say it), that it is possible to ignore case in the pattern, but not in the contents. I'd like to understand how this would work (ignoring pattern, but not contents -- or the other way around).

Comment: In `less`, for example, there's a `-i` mode in which matching is case-insensitive if you only use lowercase letters in the pattern, but if there are any uppercase letters in the pattern, the whole thing is case-sensitive. That's like (sometimes) ignoring case in the contents but not the pattern.

Comment: less is an interactive program quite unlike grep, not sure how it relates at all. interactive programs make usability choices, like nano where you can change case-sensitivity by hotkey. As for the manpage I think the old text actually explained it better, the new one does not make clear the pattern meaning itself changes too (even if [A-z] example is a bit constructed, the match result is completely different, so it should be in the manpage, but isn't anymore).

Answer (score 6):

> "It ignores case in the file (contents) but also in the pattern",
>   this suggests (although it doesn't necessarily say it),
>   that it is possible to ignore case in the pattern, but not in the contents. 
>   I'd like to understand how this would work
>   (ignoring pattern, but not contents -- or the other way around).

Well, for example, it could be written
so that a pattern of “hello” would match “Hello” in the file,
but not vice versa. 
While this sounds hypothetical, it is the way spell-check works. 
If your dictionary contains “stack” and “exchange”,
and your document contains “Stack Exchange”,
spell-check will succeed without error. 
But if your dictionary contains “Unix” and your document contains “unix”,
that will be flagged as an error.

Answer (score 6):

Using the -i flag ignores the case of the matches, not the case of the filenames. You created a file whose name is all uppercase, but you told grep to open a file whose name is lowercase, leading to the "file not found" error message. Linux filenames are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

"in both the PATTERN and the input files" = "in the pattern and *in* the input files".  The preposition "in" applies to both clauses joined by "both".

If the authors had intended to ignore case distinctions in both the PATTERN and the input filenames, they would have said so.

---

In comments, OP explains that the Question is incorrectly framed.  In response to OP's *actual* difficulty: The first line of the description on the man page you cite is "grep searches the named input FILEs (...) for lines containing a match to the given PATTERN." That is, grep searches for matches to the contents of files not for matches to their names.

Of course, OP's clarification makes the accepted answer nonresponsive to the hidden question.

Comment: That doesn't address my problem at all. I interpreted it as you suggest. I take issue with the meaning of "files". Why should it mean "file's contents"? I interpreted it as it being their names. Ultimately a file is neither its contents, nor their names.

Comment: Another thing that led to my confusion and led to the above-mentioned point, is that "ignoring case in the pattern, but not in the contents" is a concept that is extremely alien to me. In my mind if case is ignored in the pattern, then it is also ignored in the contents. Why then, reference contents if it is not possible to ignore case in the pattern, but not in the contents? I thought "OK, if this is being referenced, then surely it doesn't mean the file's contents, but the filenames".

Comment: @grep : You did not interpret it as I suggest.  "in files" is not their filenames.  Filenames are on the outside of files.  For example, where in the file `whatever` is the string "whatever"?

Comment: I interpreted it as "in the pattern and in the input files". The thing is, you look at the word *files* here and think of its contents. I do not. What I meant with "I interpreted as you suggest" is that your rewording doesn't address my issue at all. It could have be worded as you suggest, and it would have led to my confusion anyway.

Comment: @grep : you cannot have a "distinction" if only one thing is present.  "case distinctions" requires two different things be listed so that they can be distinct.  "case distinctions in the PATTERN" is incomplete.  Distinct from what?

Comment: @grep : Are any of your contents your name?  How would anyone assume a label is content of the thing labelled?

Comment: Of course a name is not its contents. I just don't see that the man page is saying that it is going to go look in the contents. That's the whole point, both you and the man page start from an assumption that I do not make: that `grep` is going to look into content.

Comment: @grep : First line of the description: "grep searches the named input FILEs (or standard input if no files are named, or if a single hyphen-minus (-) is given as file name) for lines containing a match to the given PATTERN."

Comment: I've already addressed this. I don't look at "file" and think of its contents. A file is neither its contents, nor its name, it's something else. There's an interpretative effort here. Despite the fact that a file is not its contents, you interpreted it that way. I did not. This discussion is not productive for you, nor for me. I do not care to convince you my opinion, so I'll be ceasing communications on this matter.

Comment: @grep : Either you read the first line of the description that directly informs you that grep searches the lines in files for matches or you didn't.  Since apparently you did not read that line, you have no basis to complain that the documentation is incorrect.